# Need a conditional statement to fill a column based off a string

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, where-clause

I need to fill cells in a column based off if another column contains a certain string.

I need to fill column B based off what's in C. 
Like if C contains 'hello;', then fill the corresponding cell in B with 'greet'. Then if C contains 'bye;', fill the corresponding cells in B with 'farewell'.

```
df1
   A    B       C        D
0  w       hello; Jon    q
1  x       bye; Jon      r
2  y       hello; Jack   s
3  z       bye; Jack     t
```

```
df1['B'] = np.where(df1['C'].str.contains('hello;'), 'greet', '')
df1['B'] = np.where(df1['C'].str.contains('bye;'), 'farewell', '')
```

This works; however, the next line of code overwrites the 'greet' from the first line. So I'm not sure how to combine the conditionals so they don't overwrite each other. 
What I want the end result to be is

```
df1
   A    B          C          D
0  w  greet     hello; Jon    q
1  x  farewell  bye; Jon      r
2  y  greet     hello; Jack   s
3  z  farewell  bye; Jack     t
```

Comment: when you run the second `np.where` you will overwrite the contents of `B` since you're explicitly telling python to do that. Instead of `np.where` look at `np.select`

Comment: `df1['C'].str.extract(r'(hello|bye)')[0].map({'hello': 'greet', 'bye': 'farewell'})`

Comment: Or nest the `np.where()` functions within one another, but I agree that native pandas solutions are best

Comment: Never nest `np.where`.  That is exactly what `np.select` is for.  The former is unreadable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

```
m1= df['C'].str.contains('hello;')
m2= df['C'].str.contains('bye;')

df['B'] = np.select(condlist=[m1 , m2], 
                         choicelist=['greet','farewell'])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you’re only going to be dealing with a binary choice and all the values exist in the column, as per the example, then this should be fine:

```
 df1['B'] = np.where(df1['C'].str.contains('bye;'), 'farewell', 'greet')
```

From the [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

> numpy.where(condition[, x, y])
>
> Return elements chosen from x or y depending on condition.

If the condition is satisfied, it will return `x`, else it will fill with `y`.

However, `np.select` [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) will be the one you want if you have more than one condition:

```
conditions = [
    df['C'].str.contains('hello;'),
    df['C'].str.contains('bye;')
]

np.select(conditions, ['greet', 'farewell'])
```

```
array(['greet', 'farewell', 'greet', 'farewell'], dtype='<U11')
```

Comment: NMDV, but if you are using `np.select`, you might as well put working code that solves the question, not just copy something from the documentation.

Comment: @user3483203 only on my phone so it’s hard to test/type (no straight quotes on ze iPhone). Also, what does NMDV mean?

Comment: Not my downvote.  I'll update your answer with a working version.

Comment: Ta. I was downvoted before I even included the np.select edit anyway. Slightly confused, as np.where works perfectly fine in a binary choice case.